# No sound after upgrade from Xubuntu 13.10 to 14.04

Tags: sound, xubuntu, 14.04

No sound, pavucontrol only shows "dummy output".
`aplay` gives nothing, `lspci` shows soundcard:

```
04:01.0 Audio device: VIA Technologies, Inc. VT8237A/VT8251 HDA Controller
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device 7318
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 17
    Memory at dfafc000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
```

Didn't find any solution around the web. what can I do?

Comment: seems to be a bug in the kernel with my sound card: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1265611

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
    rm -r ~/.config/pulse
    pulseaudio --kill
```

I also logged out and in in-between these two commands, but the `pulseaudio --kill` did it for me.

Oh and finally I also had to run pavucontrol and meddle with the output choices once or twice:

```
    pavucontrol
```

I switched from 'Speakers' to 'Analogue Output', and then back to 'Speakers'. Then, I got sound!

I got the ideas from this thread: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2211608&page=2&highlight=trusty+sound

Good luck

Comment: This alone did not work for me, but the provided link and some tinkering around did. First I had to use aplay -L to find what devices I had, then aplay -D sysdefault <somefile> to verify that I get a sound in this case, then I've updated ~/.pulse/<somehash>-default-sink to point at that device and finally - logout -> login.

Comment: laher, unfortunately this doesn't solve my problem, pavucontrol still shows nothing. --- Uri Barenholz: As I said, aplay doesn't show anything in my case.