# Lost all sound in Xubuntu 14.04

Tags: sound, 14.04, xubuntu, pulseaudio, alsa

The other day, all sound in my Xubuntu 14.04 installation suddenly stopped working. I first tried this:

```
rm -r ~/.config/pulse
pulseaudio --kill
```

Which was suggested [here,](https://askubuntu.com/questions/450531/no-sound-after-upgrade-from-xubuntu-13-10-to-14-04) but it didn't do the trick. I finally got my sound working again after following [this guide](http://itsfoss.com/fix-sound-ubuntu-1304-quick-tip/), using these commands:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio
sudo apt-get install alsa-base pulseaudio
```

Reboot and

```
sudo alsa force-reload
```

This worked for a while but then the sound disappeared again and trying the above steps again doesn't work. Does anyone have any ideas for what I can try to fix this? When looking in

```
pavucontrol
```

All I can see is the HDMI output on my GPU, my onboard sound isn't even listed.

Comment: Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this on a minimal xubu desktop by doing this: install 'qasmixer' then go into the menu and choose 'Settings > Sessions and Startup > Application Autostart > Add' and name it whatever (ie Volume Control) then for the command type in: `qasmixer --tray` then reboot.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
sudo start-pulseaudio-x11 start
```

then type your password and you done it

Reboot.

Comment: sudo start-pulseaudio-x11 stop and then start works for me! thank you.